# how to replace multiple characters in a single string using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to import CSV file data into MySql using PHP.I got the code to do this. The data in CSV may contain single quotes and commas within it.I used str_replace to fix the issue.It replaces only one of the characters.But I want to replace both.

example:

```
Broad Oak Road, Accrington, Lancashire, BB5 2AW United Kingdom.

Road King's College Aberdeen
```

I have used str_replace("'","\'",$csv_array[0]) to replace single quotes.Is there any way to replace both using a single PHP function? Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you *replace* those characters? What "issue" is there?

Comment: The issue is when I try to insert the CSV data to my DB,it shows syntax error.That's why I tried to replace it.

Comment: Then you need to properly prepare your values to be entered into the database. Removing characters is not the answer! Read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: What is your field seperator? Anything aside a comma? Instead you can't differenciate between sentence marks and field separators. Or do you want to store the whole stinge in one db field?

Comment: when you replace the commas and quotes from a text, you may change its meaning. Thats to be aware of! Better to escape the crucial characters

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
str_replace('"', "", $string);
str_replace("'", "", $string);
```

I know it's not one line of code, but this will work also.